# PHP file search works in WAMP but not in LAMP

Tags: php, wamp, virtualbox, lamp

I wrote a PHP script to find video files and tested it on my local WAMP server. It works there. However, when the script is moved onto my LAMP server, the script is unable to find the same files. It checks if the specified directory exists, so I know it sees the /var/www/videos directory (script is run from /var/www/web).

The LAMP server is being run on VirtualBox, and /var/www/videos is mounted to the directory on my Windows 7 host machine I used during the script's development.

My best guess is something related to permissions, does that sound like the right path?

Script is here: http://pastebin.com/9MTKaUep
--one mistake, the last if statement is the following on my LAMP version:

```
if (isset($search)):
        $videos = glob_files($search, '../videos');
endif;
```

Permissions look like the following

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   177 Feb 21 22:44 index.html
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root 49152 Feb 21 22:53 videos
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root  4096 Feb 21 23:29 web
```

Comment: may be some file permission issue.

Comment: The root ownership looks wrong. Change the user or the group so that the user running the web server can execute the files (the X permission).

Comment: @halfer is right - `chown` the files you are trying to access.

Comment: What Linux distribution are you using? Some distributions have stricter default security settings than others. It may be possible that the webserver is not allowed any access outside of the document root.

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 12.10. Thanks all I'll try those suggestions and report back.

Answer (score 0):

YOu may have to copy that video files folder in to the virtual box